# Splitting values from column into several columns

Tags: python, pandas

I have a  pandas dataframe that I want the numbers of the column C to be added together  and created a new column D.

For example

[image]

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please don’t use all-caps in the title, and please don’t post tables as images, post them as *tables* (consult the formatting help for the how).

Answer (score 3):

Use [`Series.str.extractall`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extractall.html) for get numbers separately, convert to integers and last sum per first level of `MultiIndex`:

```
df['D'] = df['C'].str.extractall('(\d)').astype(int).sum(level=0)
```

Comment: thanks jezrael...that was really helpfull